Returning top value with associated columns
I am trying to get the top row for each city.  I want to know the key and the count associated with the top row.
Assume the following data
Key City        City_count
13  Columbus    30
4   Columbus    17
16  Grove City  15  
29  Columbus    27

I need the SQL to return, for each CITY, give me the top City_count, and the Key for that City_count value.  In the above data set, the output should return
Key City        City_count
13  Columbus    30
16  Grove City  15  

I think I need to use
(dense_rank first order by city, city_count desc) over (partition by city), but I can’t get it to return what I need.  What am I doing wrong?

You can use row_number with a partition on City to determine the row with the max value, then select it:
select t.Key
    , t.City
    , t.City_Count
from
(
    select tbl.*
        , row_number() over (partition by tbl.City order by tbl.City_Count desc) rn
    from tbl 
) t
where t.rn = 1

